# Powershell WMIInvoke Double Hop issue

Tags: powershell

Basically I'm trying to kick a jar off on a remote machine that will fire and forget. To solve this I found the WMIInvoke method does the best job at firing and forgetting.

```
$Username = "domain\username"
$Password = "password"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

$p = Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "java -jar \\networklocation\runableJar.jar params" -ComputerName 10.1.1.1 -Credential $Cred
```

I use the $p to fetch the process ID so that my program can remember which processes are running and end them if needed.

The remote machine has access the network location, the user has rights to the network location, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to use Invoke-WmiMethod to pass in the correct credentials. I can't even have it write to the C:\Temp folder. Can anyone give me any pointers here? From reading online this might be a double hop issue and is addressed via the Invoke method and sessions. However this method is not fire and forget like I want it to be.

Comment: sounds like a classic double hop issue. The user is able to pass their creds to the remote machine but the remote machine cant pass it on to the network location to write files.  I would look into kerberos authentication. It can allow the remote machine to pass cred to the network location.

Comment: Try adding `-Impersonation Delegate` to Invoke-WmiMethod

Comment: @mikez I tried that before (but with 1-5) and I get this error: "Invoke-WmiMEthod: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread"

Comment: @DaneBoulton do you have any good articles for how to use Kerberos Authentication? Some googling around led me to a few places but not sure if I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: Here is what I used to get it working in the past found it super usefull in troubleshooting kerberos. If you can set up an IIS site it will help you get it configured and if it works there it should be able to work for other services than just IIS.  All depends on how restrictive you set the kerberos permissions in AD.  http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2009/06/delegconfig-v2-beta-%28delegation-kerberos-configuration-tool%29

Comment: I gave up anyways... switched to straight up C# which I will ask in another question. Still facing the same issue but unrelated to powershell now.